# How do I make a div visible in tablets with bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, visible

I have two `<li>` tags, i would like one showing only when the device is small and the other in the other cases.
So I have the following
visible-md visible-lg in one and hidden-md hidden-lg in the other one.
It works for the desktop and the phone but not for tablets.
What should i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class visible-md to your li and the other with visible-xs. 
You can check this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities for more references